# Sticky header of recyclerView Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to make a header of recyclerView sticky.

[image]

Now the header scrolls with the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not mine, but i used it with combination with collectionview
https://github.com/xamcat/Scratch/tree/master/FormsStickyHeaders

Also there is issue on xamarin github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8656